# How can I reformat the GECOS field with Perl or awk?

Tags: perl, awk

I want to scan the `passwd` file and change the order of words in the comment field from **firstname lastname** to **lastname firstname**, and force the surname to capitals.

So, change every line from:

```
jbloggs:x:9999:99:Joe Bloggs:/home/jbloggs:/bin/ksh
```

to:

```
jbloggs:x:9999:99:BLOGGS Joe:/home/jbloggs:/bin/ksh
```

I'm new to Perl and I'm having problems with different field separators in awk.
Appreciate any help.

Comment: What problem are you having with AWK field separators?

Comment: Why do some of the solutions below output the records out of there original order?

Comment: @paul44 Are you using comma-separated GECOS information, or do all entries in your password file have "<first> <last>" as in your example?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Passwd::Unix](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Passwd::Unix) or [Passwd::Linux](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Passwd::Linux).

Answer (score 1):

Stand-alone example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $s = 'jbloggs:x:9999:99:Joe Bloggs:/home/jbloggs:/bin/ksh';
my @tokens = split /:/, $s;
my ($first, $last) = split /\s+/, $tokens[4];
$tokens[4] = uc($last) . " $first";
print join(':', @tokens), "\n";

__END__
jbloggs:x:9999:99:BLOGGS Joe:/home/jbloggs:/bin/ksh
```

As a script (output to STDOUT; must redirect output to a file):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my @tokens = split /:/;
    my ($first, $last) = split /\s+/, $tokens[4];
    $tokens[4] = uc($last) . " $first";
    print join(':', @tokens), "\n";
}
```

Comment: This fails for comma delimited GECOS fields and gives a "Use of uninitialized value $first in concatenation (.) or string" error for some records.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F":" ' { split($5,a," ");$5=toupper(a[2])" "a[1] } 1 ' OFS=":" /etc/passwd
jbloggs:x:9999:99:BLOGGS Joe:/home/jbloggs:/bin/ksh
```

Comment: Fails for GECOS fields that are comma delimited. Adds a space to the beginning of the GECOS field if it consists of only one word.

Comment: let's not get too far ahead here.

Answer (score 1):

`$ awk -v FS=":" '{split($5, a, " "); name = toupper(a[2]) " " a[1]; gsub($5, name); print $0}' passwd`

Won't work if you have middle names though.

Edit: easier to read version

```
awk -v FS=":" '
{
    split($5, name_parts, " ")
    name = toupper(name_parts[2]) " " name_parts[1]
    gsub($5, name)
    print $0
}' passwd
```

Comment: `$5 = name` works just fine, no need for `gsub`.  Also, I think you want a `-v OFS=:` too.  `print` with no argument prints `$0`, but I guess that's a matter of taste.

Comment: `$5 = name` doesn't work without the `-v OFS=:`. If you don't include both you get the fields space-separated. `gsub()` replaces the contents of `$0` with the result, so in my script I don't need to worry about `OFS`.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're doing there now.  Hmm, what if `$5 = "."`?  Dangerous.

Comment: Fails for empty GECOS fields, ones that contain only one word and those that are comma delimited.

Comment: thanks everyone - this is great.  What if the GECOS contains $firstname $lastname $otherstuff - 
eg - bloggs:x:9999:99:Joe Bloggs temp (Sales):/home/jbloggs:/bin/ksh
So I just want to operate on the full name, as above, and discard the rest of the GECOS?

Answer (score 1):

This will process the file as  you read it and put the new format entries into the array @newEntries.

```
open PASSWD, "/etc/passwd";
while(<PASSWD>) {
    @fields = split /:/;
    ($first, $last) = split (/\s/, $fields[4]);
    $last = uc $last;
    $fields[4] = "$last $first";
    push @newEntries, join(':', @fields);
}
```

Comment: Shorter: `$fields[4] = "\U$last\E $first";`, skip the manual `uc`.  Well, it's equivalent anyhow...

Comment: Adds a space to empty or one-word GECOS fields. Fails for comma-delimited ones.

Comment: +1 Good point...I focused too much on the specific example and didn't make it general.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ perl -pe 's/^((.*:){4})(\S+)\s+(\S+?):/$1\U$4\E, $3:/' \
    /etc/passwd >/tmp/newpasswd
```

To rewrite only those users who have logged in within the past sixty days according to `lastlog`, you might use

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -n

use warnings;
use strict;

use Date::Parse;

my($user) = /^([^:]+):/;
die "$0: $ARGV:$.: no user\n" unless defined $user;

if ($user eq "+") {
  next;
}

my $lastlog = (split " ", `lastlog -u "$user" | sed 1d`, 4)[-1];
die "$0: $ARGV:$.: lastlog -u $user failed\n"
  unless defined $lastlog;

my $time_t = str2time $lastlog;

# rewrites users who've never logged in
#next if defined $time_t && $time_t < ($^T - 60 * 24 * 60 * 60);

# users who have logged in within the last sixty days
next unless defined $time_t && $time_t >= ($^T - 60 * 24 * 60 * 60);

s/^((.*:){4})(\S+)\s+(\S+?):/$1\U$4\E, $3:/;
print;
```

as in

```
$ ./fixusers /etc/passwd >/tmp/fixedusers
```

Comment: Fails for comma delimited GECOS fields.

Comment: @Dennis It probably fails for lots of formats that paul44 didn't mention in the question.

Comment: I have already cleaned up the GECOS field as far as I could - this works just fine for me now - thanks.
Incidentally - is there an easy way to take the first field (username) and tell if he has logged in recently (say, comparing to a lastlog -u) and only output if the user has logged in in, say, tha last 60 days, so stipping out users who have been idle for 2 months?

Comment: Format of a lastlog is below.  Does perl have a funky way of checking the last login date and excluding any who have never logged in or not for 60 days?

[root@server1 paul]# lastlog -u bsmith
Username         Port     From             Latest
bsmith            pts/2    172.21.83.181    Mon Oct 19 16:10:56 +0100 2009
[root@itdev5 paul]# lastlog -u jbloggs
Username         Port     From             Latest
jbloggs                                   **Never logged in**

All the responses above have been really useful - just this last favour, please - cheers.

Comment: @paul44 See the "rewrites users who've never logged in" comment? Uncomment the following line, and comment out the "next unless..." a couple of lines down.